# Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring-security

Could someone help me on this. appreciate your help.

I am using Spring security 3.1 with create-session="stateless" option.
Which throwing "InsufficientAuthenticationException" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource" exception  of ExceptionTranslationFilter.

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong and why I am getting this exception . As this exception stated that the credentials are not proper but I can see the credentials are going through request.Still I am getting 401 unauthorized

Fact is that the user is able to login properly & I get the message on console also. But again it is redirecting to login page due to access denied exception.

Here I am putting the code

**Spring-Security.xml**

```
<http entry-point-ref="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint"
         create-session="stateless" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/loginuser"  access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>   
         <custom-filter ref="securityContextPersistenceFilter"          after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <custom-filter ref="ldapAuthFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />                
        <custom-filter ref="databaseAuthFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
</http> 


<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <property name='securityContextRepository'>
            <bean class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
                <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Please, edit your question's title to be an actual question, as it currently is not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that's exactly what stateless is meant to do.

Once you set create-session parameter as stateless, on every http call the [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.html) won't be even called (by default) or, even if you force it to be called according to your configuration, it won't be any session level security information in the SecurityContextHolder.

This stateless pattern is intended to be used in a Rest style architecture, where authentication and authorization information is sent on every request. Better said, I don't think that stateless session creation pattern should be used unless you are developing a full stateless application

I found a good post about this, [Spring Security Session Management](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session), look carefully section *2. When Is The Session Created?*

So stateless session creation strategy does not fit to a classic login form pattern.

In your scenario, I guesss that what is happening is that, once the login request is completed and the request is authenticathed, it is probably redirecting to a kind of welcome page using an HTTP 301 or 302 redirect, redirection which again is not carrying authentication info, so ends redirecting again to login page.

If you simply use "ifRequired" as session-creation, or as it is the default value, just don't set it, I bet your login would end successfully and redirect to wherever it should correctly without asking to log in again. And, if you do it like this, avoid setting the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, it is configured automatically.

Comment: Thanks lumietu.. yes that will definitely work if i use "ifrequired" but do you think it would be stateless app. Because it is creating session ultimately

Comment: As you said login form pattern does not fit to stateless session creation. then how can we exclude that login form to being stateless and other request to be stateless.

Comment: If you want to securize a stateless application you must send authentication information in every request, or even use a kind of session token.

Comment: When I am trying to pass username and password in header on every request that time I m getting 401 Unauthorized resposne. can u know any link where i will get this kind of example with login and then secure other request  with token.

Comment: I got your point that application is not stateless. The http calls which we are making are stateless that is what we have set in create session.  So in my case the calls becomes stateless and from next request I m not getting authorized request, So I have done authentication on for all request that's what the JWT is saying that we have to authorised to all request by taking data from token.